# Is it possible to forward the user to the remote URL to initiate the handshake and then automatically go back to where the user just wanted to go?

Tags: javascript, https, ssl-certificate, insecure-connection

In my webapp, which is running on a locally hosted webserver running at port 5005, makes requests  to an remote backend running in Java at port 7575. This backend offers an SSL 3.0 enabled https connection to secure the transfer between client and server. The used certificate is self-signed and thereby not trusted by the Browser.

The problem is, that the browser immediately aborts the request, but on the UI nothing happens. The browser isn't even asking whether to trust the certificate or not. If i open the requested URL just by copy and paste from the Chrome network tracking, it asks for trusting the certificate and i can confirm. Afterwards the app works just fine as expected, until i restart the browser.

So my question is how i can solve this issue? Is it possible to forward the user to the remote URL to initiate the handshake and then automatically go back to where the user just wanted to go?
I know that I can install the certificate locally, but this is not very convenient, especially because i want the user to connect to multiple back-end instances which addresses many changes. Can I add this certificate programmatically to browser using JavaScript? Is there any way to add or import this certificate in the browsers programmatically using javscript ?